# How to take data (item ID, item names, item price) from a file with FileChooser and list item ID in a combobox? How to match labels to selection?

Tags: javafx, combobox, properties, binding, filechooser

I am trying to make point of sale terminal. I need to read read (item ID, item names, and item price) from a text file with FileChooser. Then the itemID should be listed in a comboBox. The comboBox selection should change labels and prices to the corresponding item name and item price. I believe this has to do with properties and binding but I don't understand how to use those.

I've tried creating an Items class, I tried reading the file into three arrays and then comparing the ID array item to the combobox selection and then switching the label text to the name array item with the same position.

```
stage.setTitle("Open Resource File");
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    try { 
        FileReader reader = new 
FileReader(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            itemID[i] = scanner.next();
            itemName[i] = scanner.next();
            itemPrice[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
        }
        scanner.close();
        reader.close();
        }
    catch (Exception FileNotFoundException) {

    }



Items item = new Items();
    ComboBox idBox = new ComboBox();
    idBox.setPromptText("Select an item");
    idBox.getItems().addAll("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", 
"J");
    idBox.setOnAction(e -> {
        item.setName(idBox.getValue().toString(), itemID, itemName);
        item.setPrice(idBox.getValue().toString(), itemID, itemPrice);
        nameLbl.setText(item.name.toString());
    });

    double quantity;
    Label idLabel = new Label("Item ID: ");
    Label nameLabel = new Label("Item Name: ");
    Label nameLbl = new Label(item.name.toString());
    Label priceLabel = new Label("Item Price: ");
    Label priceLbl = new 
Label(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(newLocale("en", 
"US")).format(item.price));    
    Label priceLbl = new Label("");

Program compiles and main window opens but shows error and crashes when 
it tries to create the point of sales terminal window.
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a number of things you're going to want to look into, this isn't going to contain all the code, but it should be enough to get you going.

1) You're going to want to scan your Items into an `ObservableList<Item>` so that you have them in a single List to work with.  At a bare minimum you can do something like this in your for:

```
String id = scanner.next();
String name = scanner.next();
String price = scanner.nextDouble();
items.add(new Item(id, name, price));
```

although you probably want to make the looping within the scanner a little more dynamic (instead of to 10) - possibly use a while loop or a different reader.

2) Now that you have your list of Items you want to use a `ComboBox<Item> cbItems = new ComboBox<Item>()` in order to display.  You're going to have to set the `cbItems.setCellFactory(...)` and `cbItems.setButtonFactory(...)` in order to display the Id or the name in the drop down.   The ObservableList you've added to can then be set to the `cbItems.setItems(items)` described in (1).  There are a ton of SO articles on doing so, so I'll leave out the full code.

3) It's dealers choice on whether you want to use `ObjectProperty<Item>` or `cbItems.selectedProperty()` in order to bind to the text boxes that you're using.  'd suggest starting with the on change handler you're using now and setting the labels directly with `item.getName()` and once you've got that working move on to `lblName.textProperty().bind(Bindings....)`.

With regards to the error, you haven't posted enough information (what the exception is, or the full code to replicate) so I can't help in that way.  But if you research the items above, you should be closer.